# Unable to extract data from json while calling webservice on server side

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, web-services, serialization

On Client Side

```
 var pre = "{\"objEmployees\": {\"Employee\": [{";
 var array = JSON.stringify(employee);
 var last = "}}";
 var ArrayofObjects = pre + array + last;
 DoSort(ArrayofObjects);  

 function DoSort(ArrayofObjects) {
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 dataType: "json",
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 url: "http://localhost:50214/CMSWebService.asmx/sorting",
 data: ArrayofObjects,
 success: function (response) {
 alert('done');
 },
 error: function (response) {
 alert(response.d);
 }
 });
 }
```

This is My entities

```
[Serializable]
public class Employee
{
    public string id;
    public string order;
}
public class Employees :List<Employee>
{

}
```

On Server Side in web service

```
[WebMethod]
[WebInvoke(RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat= ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string sorting(Employees objEmployees)
{   
int ID = Convert.ToInt32(objEmployees[0].id);
int Order = Convert.ToInt32(objEmployees[0].order);
// Update code....
return "true";
}
```

This Code hits my service but i am unable to extract values at webservice. I am getting null object.Even ths signature of webservice matches with data in ajax call.

Comment: I don't think the JSON data will translate to List<Employee>, try setting the parameter of sorting to Employee[]. And also change the 'pre' into: `var pre = "{\"objEmployees\": [{";`

Comment: @HåkanFahlstedt var pre will remain same already tried almost everything

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer
    `var array = JSON.stringify(objemployee: employee);`